# How does one measure the power factor?

Tags: electric-circuits, measurements, power

How does one measure the power factor?

$$\text{power factor}\equiv\frac{\text{power}}{|V||I|}=\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+(1/\omega^2C^2)}}$$ for an RC circuit driven with $V(t)=V_0\cos{(\omega t)}$.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you could also try the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange... http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hft Yes, they may be able to answer better. thank you

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/138582/72280), [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/82188/72280), and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/51320/72280) question there seem to answer my question here.